# Symfony2 Query Builder "SELECT where sum children > 0"

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, query-builder

I am trying to gather a result set of orders that have children, OrderPayments. I want to have only the orders where the sum of orderpayments.amount > 0.

So far I have this but can't get it to work, I get a

Column not found: Unknown column 'sclr_0' in 'where clause'

```
    // Create the Query Builder
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')->select('o');

    // Joins
    $qb->leftJoin('o.orderPayments', 'op')->addSelect('op')->addSelect('SUM(op.amount) AS total_sum');

    // Criteria
    $qb->where('total_sum > 0');
    $qb->andWhere('o.dateDeleted IS NULL');

    // Return the result
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Have you check full query in log? @Adam

Comment: Clear your cache. Run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`. If after these actions you still have this error message, add here your entity class code and whole SQL-query that Doctrine generates.

Comment: @AnkiiG I checked it and it is basically the SELECT SUM(o.orderPayments) AS sclr_0 part that relates to sclr_0 not found.

Comment: @Michael unfortunately that doesn't help me at all as my migrations and diffs are all up to date. That was an obvious check before posting on here

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried your sql query in your database?

You query looks like:

```
SELECT o.*, SUM(op.amount) AS total 
FROM order o 
LEFT JOIN order_payement op on o.id = op.order_id
WHERE total > 0;
```

This query will not work on mysql, you can't use result of operation on SELECT clause in your WHERE clause.

Your query must looks like:

```
SELECT o.*, SUM(op.amount) AS total 
FROM order o 
LEFT JOIN order_payement op on o.id = op.order_id
HAVING SUM(op.amount) > 0
GROUP BY o.id;
```

And your query builder will be:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
   ->select('o');
   ->leftJoin('o.orderPayments', 'op')
   ->addSelect('op')
   ->addSelect('SUM(op.amount) AS total_sum')
   ->Where('o.dateDeleted IS NULL')
   ->having('SUM(op.amount) > 0')
   ->grouBy('o.id');
```

Comment: That makes some sense though the updated query builder still throws the same error...